# Select or Drop time-value pairs in TimeSeries

Tags: filtering, time-series

I have an `EventSeries` object and I would like to keep/drop some time-value pairs in it based on a criterion, e.g., comparing to a threshold or what have you. What is the correct way to do it? I can extract paths, work with them and create a new `TimeSeries` but this looks wrong.

Comment: Did you look into [`DeleteCases'](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html?q=DeleteCases)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
v = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
es = EventSeries[v, {t}];

 TimeSeriesWindow[es, {2, 11}]["Path"]
```

> {{2, 1}, {5, 6}, {10, 5}}

```
Select[2 <= #[[1]] <= 11&] @ es["Path"]
```

> {{2, 1}, {5, 6}, {10, 5}}

```
DeleteCases[_?(#[[1]] <= 5 || #[[2]] <= 4 &)]@es["Path"]
```

> {{10, 5}, {12, 7}}